# Speech to text wit.ai telegram bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm making a telegram bot. Using node js (node-telegram-bot-api), axios, wit.ai. Voice to text not working. What i doing wrong?I need to translate a voice message into text, but my script does not work

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const TelegramApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const bot = new TelegramApi(process.env.TOKEN, { polling: true })
const axios = require('axios')

bot.on('voice', async (msg) => {
  const stream = bot.getFileStream(msg.voice.file_id)

  let chunks = []

  stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk))
  stream.on('end', () => {
    const axiosConfig = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://api.wit.ai/speech',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + WIT_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'audio/ogg',
      },
      data: Buffer.concat(chunks),
    }
    axios(axiosConfig)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('answer', response.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('error', err)
      })
  })
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPLZX.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just need to translate a voice message into text